# What would be the best way to link 3 many to many join tables in Spring JPA?

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa, database-design, many-to-many

I am working on a project for which I need to model a school management system. The problem I am facing is that I have 3 intermediate join tables linking to each other which I feel is inefficient.

- I have subjects, teachers, students and assignments.
- Subject and Teacher is many to many.
- SubjectTeacherJoin and Students is many to many.
- StudentSubjectTeacherJoin and Assignments is many to many.

Currently I am using a join table with a separate key and many to one mappings.
This has made the querying and management rather complex.
Will going with composite keys be a better option? Or are there any other simplifications?

Answer (score 0):

To me, it's ok to use a join table with a separate key and many to one mapping, since in this way you have your join table as a separate entity that is conventional in the SQL world. You could also provide a more convenient name for it that fits your business case like for example `SubjectTeacherJoin` and `Students` could be a `CourseAtendee` and `StudentSubjectTeacherJoin` and `Assignments` could be `Schedule` or something similar to that. It's up to you to name it. As the next stage, I would also think about what queries will run at most. Since most of the operations are read operations, so you will not benefit from having quite complex joins for the most used queries in your system. This leads me to another suggestion which is denormalization. You could add to your intermediate tables a few fields that need at most queries so in this case you could mitigate the load and omit complex join for all queries. And if you would have a few duplicates of data which makes you feel uncomfortable think that it could be an acceptable tradeoff for simplifying your queries and increasing performance.